# Solspace Calendar error after install

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

When I installed the calendar plugin, the first thing I noticed was that the channels did not auto install themselves. Can I add them manually?

Also now when adding content to any channel I receive the following once I hit 'publish', `A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT channel_id FROM exp_channels WHERE

Filename: third_party/calendar/data.calendar.php

Line Number: 578`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an error with another plugin. Once I resolved that I was able to reinstall Calendar correctly.

Comment: Which plugin for future reference to anyone else with the same issue?

Comment: I have a custom version of color picker plus and I tried leaving backups of the original files with the regular files. For some reason EE was confused by that so I removed them and now have the original backups locally.

Comment: Ahh. The way ee works, you shouldn't leave backup folders of any add-ons in the actual 'thirdparty' folder.

Comment: Good to know. I was trying to make it easier for other coders working on the site to find the relevant source material but I'll have to just keep an organized local structure.